# How to update data in a table, shopping cart style? Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning Vue and I am making a shopping cart style table, I have the problem that when I INCREASE and DECREASE from the table the quantity does not increase or decrease in the visual part, but if I inspect the component and the data inside the array if the quantity is updated, I attach image.

[image]

I attach an image of how is the table, as you can see it is a simple common table of a shopping cart, I saw other tutorials or people who have done it but it still does not work, I do not know if I'm missing something else or I'm doing wrong the part of auto increase the amount of the row.

[image]

Attached is the script code and template

```
                <table class="table" ref="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th
                            v-for="(head, key) in fields"
                            :key="key"
                            v-text="head"
                        ></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody v-if="items.length > 0">
                        <tr v-for="(product, i) in items" :key="i">
                            <td v-text="product.code"></td>
                            <td v-text="product.name"></td>
                            <td>
                                ${{ Number(product.price).toLocaleString() }}
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                                <!-- <b-form-input type="number" min="0" class="col-8" size="sm" :value="product.stock" @change="changeStock(i)"></b-form-input> -->
                                <a
                                    class="btn iq-bg-danger"
                                    @click="decrement(i)"
                                    v-bind:disabled="product.count <= 1"
                                    >-</a
                                ><!-- v-bind:disabled="product.count<=1" -->
                                {{ product.count }}
                                <a
                                    class="btn iq-bg-primary"
                                    @click="increment(i)"
                                    >+</a
                                >
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                                <b-input-group>
                                    <b-form-input
                                        type="number"
                                        min="0.00"
                                        class="col-8"
                                        size="sm"
                                        value="0"
                                    ></b-form-input>
                                    <b-input-group-append>
                                        <b-input-group-text>
                                            %
                                        </b-input-group-text>
                                    </b-input-group-append>
                                </b-input-group>
                            </td>
                            <td>${{ sumTotalproduct(product.price) }}</td>
                            <td width="10">
                                <a
                                    href="#"
                                    v-b-tooltip.hover
                                    title="Quitar de la cotización"
                                    @click="deleteItem(i)"
                                    ><i
                                        class="ri-delete-bin-2-line text-danger"
                                    ></i
                                ></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>NETO</td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                ${{ Number(totalNeto).toLocaleString() }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>IVA (19%)</td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                ${{ Number(totalIVA).toLocaleString() }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>TOTAL</td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                ${{ Number(total).toLocaleString() }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

export default {
    name: 'Quote',
    data () {
        return {
            fields: [
                'Código',
                'Producto',
                'Precio',
                'Cantidad',
                'Descuento',
                'Total',
                'Acción'
            ],
            items: [],
            hover: true,
            dark: false,
            noCollapse: true,
            headVariant: null,
            tableVariant: '',
            productSelected: null,
            options: [],
            chooseProduct: null,
            products: []
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.getProducts()
    },
    computed: {
        totalNeto: function () {
            var sum = 0
            this.items.forEach(e => {
                sum += e.price
            })

            return sum
        },
        totalIVA: function () {
            return parseInt(this.totalNeto * 0.19)
        },
        total: function () {
            return this.totalNeto + this.totalIVA
        },
    },
    methods: {
        openSideBarModal () {
            this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'my-sidebar')
        },
        getProducts () {
            axios.get(route('products.listAll')).then(res => {
                this.options = res.data.data
            })
        },
        currentDataItems () {
            var stock = 1
            // Obtenemos los datos del producto.
            var data = this.options.find(p => p.id == this.chooseProduct.id)

            // Validamos que no exista el dato ya en la tabla.
            if (this.items.length > 0) {
                var existData = this.items.some(d => d.id == data.id)
                if (!existData) {
                    data.count = 1 //data.stock + stock
                    this.items.push(data)
                    // }else{
                    //     data.stock += data.stock + stock
                }

                return
            }

            data.count = 1
            this.items.push(data)
            console.log(this.items)
        },
        sumTotalproduct (price) {
            return Number(price).toLocaleString()
        },
        increment (i) {
            this.items[i].count++
        },
        decrement (i) {
            if (this.items[i].count == 0) return
            this.items[i].count--
        },
        deleteItem (index) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: '¿Estas seguro de quitar el producto?',
                text:
                    'Recuerda, que puedes volver a añadir al carro el producto.',
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#283669',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Si, quitar!'
            }).then(result => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    this.items.splice(index, 1)

                    Swal.fire(
                        'Eliminado!',
                        'El producto se a elimina de la cotización.',
                        'success'
                    )
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here likely has to do with [Vue 2's reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) system. When you change a member of an object or array, Vue only knows to watch for and react to it if it is defined in the vue object or if you tell it to by using Vue.set(). if you change your code to this it should work.

```
increment(i) {
  this.$set(this.items[i], count, this.items[i] + 1);
},
decrement(i) {
  if (!this.items[i].count) return;
  this.$set(this.items[i], count, this.items[i] - 1);
}
```

Rohìt's answer worked because he defined all the objects in the data function.

Comment: I update the data if I inspect it is increasing, but visually still showing 1, until I do not add another object to the table then the counter is updated, I would have to define it as watch maybe?

Comment: you could define it as a watch, though that isn't usually needed in vue. the other thing you could do is break it up into individual components. that way, when the component is created you know for a fact it will see the changes.

Comment: wrong syntax. the property name should be passed as a string -> "count"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what issue you are facing but it is working fine for me. I juts created a working code snippet. Please have a look and let me know if any further changes required in that.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      count: 0
    }, {
      count: 0
    }, {
      count: 0
    }, {
      count: 0
    }, {
      count: 0
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    increment (i) {
      this.items[i].count++
    },
    decrement (i) {
      if (this.items[i].count == 0) return
      this.items[i].count--
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(product, i) in items" :key="i">
    <button @click="decrement(i)"
       v-bind:disabled="product.count <= 1">-</button>
    {{ product.count }}
    <button @click="increment(i)">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this code won't produce the same error that the OP was getting because you define the items in the data function.

Comment: @jaredjacobson But I did not see any error in OP, What error he is getting ?

Comment: it's not that he's getting an error, it is that the DOM isn't updating when the data does. your example will update when the data does but is designed in a way that he can't do because it is all statically defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      count: 0
    }, {
      count: 0
    }, {
      count: 5
    }, {
      count: 0
    }, {
      count: 0
    }]
  },
  methods: {
     increment(i) {
      this.$set(this.items[i], 'count', this.items[i].count + 1);
    },
    decrement(i) {
      if (!this.items[i].count) return;
      this.$set(this.items[i], 'count', this.items[i].count - 1);
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(product, i) in items" :key="`_${i}`">
    <button @click="decrement(i)">-</button>
    {{ product.count }}
    <button @click="increment(i)">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It updates if I inspect the element or if I add another element, but visually it still shows 1 until I don't add another element and so on.

Comment: I've updated the code. Run the code snippet, it's properly working.

Comment: @alexspencer
It was showing 1 because your code disabled v-bind when the count is 1. 
In the snippet above, v-bind was removed.